# OpenCL global barrier work items synchronization

Tags: c, synchronization, opencl, barrier

I'm testing an opencl kernel with four work items and a single work group. The kernel is:

```
__kernel void pgs(__global float l2_norm)
{
    int gid_x=get_global_id(0);
    int gid_y=get_global_id(1);
    if (gid_x==0 && gid_y==0) printf("[INFO] local_size_x:%02d, local_size_y:%02d, global_size_x:%02d, global_size_y:%02d, group_size_x:%02d, group_size_y:%02d\n", get_local_size(0), get_local_size(1), get_global_size(0), get_global_size(1), get_group_size(0), get_group_size(1));
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    printf("%d,%d before: %2.6f\n",gid_x,gid_y,l2_norm);
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    l2_norm+=1;
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    printf("%d,%d after: %2.6f\n",gid_x,gid_y,l2_norm);

    printf("testing %d,%d\n",gid_x,gid_y);
}
```

The output is:

```
1,1 before: 0.000000
0,1 before: 0.000000
1,0 before: 0.000000
[INFO] local_size_x:01, local_size_y:01, global_size_x:02, global_size_y:02, group_size_x:01, group_size_y:01
1,1 after: 1.000000
0,1 after: 2.000000
1,0 after: 3.000000
testing 1,1
0,0 before: 3.000000
testing 0,1
testing 1,0
0,0 after: 4.000000
testing 0,0
```

My question is: Why is the line starting with `[INFO]` not printed first? Shouldn't the global barrier stop all work items until work item 0 has printed the `[INFO]` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barrier is only for waiting in-group. Printf is flushed by clfinish so it is on kernel level synchronization. Thats why you shouldnt depend on the order of output texts but the data itself.

If it is nvidia gpu, you can use inline ptx to query clock cycles to print them and know what time it happened.

For other vendors, you can have a global atomic variable and increment it between barriers. Atomic changes dont span over barriers. This way increment of first thread will happen before others after the barrier. Since this is only data, you still need to reorder things in host environment before printf them. But this gives hint for only different sync zones. You still cant know the order in same sync zone.  You can only know that something happened before or after a barrier.

Perhaps making your own formatter is easier. Create a long buffer that wont overflow with many texts. Have a global atomic cursor counter variable. In every thread, use your formatter function similar to printf but have it increment its cursor atomically and fill trailing zone with the given formatted text. Then write whole string in host environment line by line or whatever delimiter you use in it to separate inputs.